# SendGrid for android "Dependency is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android

Tags: android, gradle, sendgrid

I am using [The SendGrid for Android](https://github.com/danysantiago/sendgrid-android) library and when I add the dependency:

```
compile 'com.github.danysantiago:sendgrid-android:1'
```

I get the warnings:

> ```
> Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
> ```

Why do I get this error and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc is clear and maybe you forget this:

Because the Library uses an updated version of [Apache's Http Library](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html) we need to add the following packaging options so the APK gets built correctly, without libraries conflicting. This goes into your app's build.gradle.

```
...
android {
   ...
    packagingOptions {
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
   }
}
```

### Edit

My app `build.gradle` file:

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hackerli.view"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
 }

 dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
      compile 'com.github.danysantiago:sendgrid-android:1'
 }
```

Comment: I get an error: `Could not find method packagingOptions() for arguments [build_kr7foz5iclxo34hjeevyopnl$_run_closure3@2f431d7f] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: @AbAppletic try again

Comment: what is your min sdk version?

Comment: My minimum API is 17

Comment: Sorry, again, I get `Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.` even with what you said

Comment: The best way is that download jar and add it to your project )

Answer (score 3):

If u already got the Apache library and still not working after adding packingOptions, try this

```
compile 'com.github.danysantiago:sendgrid-android:1',{
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
```

Comment: you are a saviour